# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Collect'

Tags: core-data, ios6

In order to wrap some logic to model, I plan to put NSManagedObjectContext in one NSManagedObject model, so I can handle many common logic in one model:

```
@interface Collect : NSManagedObject{
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *created_at;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

    - (void) initContext;
@end

@implementation Collect

    @dynamic created_at;
    @dynamic name;

    - (void) initContext{
        if (managedObjectContext == nil)
        {
           managedObjectContext = [MyAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
        }

    }
@end
```

And I use it by:

```
Collect *collect = [[Collect new] autorelease];
[collect initContext];
```

But when run it shows:`CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Collect'`.

I want to know How to add NSManagedObjectContext instance to NSManagedObject model correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a managed object context to an managed object, it works the other way around: You need a managed object context first, and then you can create objects in this context.

See e.g. the `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation:

> An instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` represents a single “object
>   space” or scratch pad in an application. Its primary responsibility is
>   to manage a collection of managed objects. These objects form a group
>   of related model objects that represent an internally consistent view
>   of one or more persistent stores. **A single managed object instance exists in one and only one context**, but multiple copies of an object
>   can exist in different contexts.

and the `NSManagedObject` documentation:

> If you instantiate a managed object directly, you **must call the designated initializer**
>   (`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`).

There is also an utility method `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` to create new objects. For example:

```
Collect *collect = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Collect"
                    inManagedObjectContext:[MyAppDelegate managedObjectContext]];
```

(You could put that into a class method of `Collect` if you like.)

And note that `NSManagedObject` already has a `managedObjectContext` method to get the context of the object:

```
NSManagedObjectContect *context = [collect managedObjectContext];
```

It is therefore not necessary (or might even cause problems) if you add an instance variable `managedObjectContext` to your managed object class.